# Plan9 file-type

Tags: filesystems, plan-9

It has been said that in plan 9 everything is a file.

Please list everything,

i.e. all things represented in the filesystem in plan9(especially things that are not files in *nix os-es).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not totally true that "everything is a file" but rather that most things have a file-like interface.  It may seem like splitting hairs, but there's a difference.  I don't think that I'll be able to list everything, but I'll give you some examples.

- The interface for TCP/IP is a filesystem, `/net` exposes "files"
- The text editor `acme` has associated control files to which textual commands may be written to change text in the window
- The mouse and keyboard are represented as data files, `/dev/mouse` for example
- The windowing system `rio` exposes a filesystem interface
- The web browser `abaco` reads from a mounted `webfs` filesystem

The interesting thing is what sort of interaction "falls out" of this arrangement.  Since most everything is text in a file somewhere, you can use normal shell scripts to implement things like an IRC client (read/write text directly to the network "file").

There are a lot of papers in the `/sys/doc` directory (and on the [web](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/sys/doc/)) about the design and implementation of Plan 9.

Answer (score 5):

For a (nearly) complete list have a look at manual sections [3 devices](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/sys/man/3/INDEX.html) and [4 file servers](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/sys/man/4/INDEX.html).

The basic idea is that [all resources look like file systems](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/sys/doc/names.html). The kernel exposes resources  in the form of devices and user programs in the form of file servers.

This allows for easy sharing of resources in a networked environment. E.g. to use the mouse that is connected to another workstation, you just map (*bind* in Plan 9 lingo) [/dev/mouse](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/magic/man2html/3/mouse) from that workstation to your name space. To use another machine as proxy for all tcp connections, just bind [/net/tcp](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/magic/man2html/3/ip) from that machine into your name space.

The details are all very well thought out and the system works nicely in practice. Browse the [documents](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/sys/doc/) and [manual pages](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/sys/man/) and if you are still curious after that, give it a try and [install it](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/wiki/plan9/installation_instructions/) to see yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Plan 9 is file-system centric, so it exposes every element of the system as a file, which was a primal philosophy of UNIX. This way a synergy is promoted into the environment and, as example, you are able to access a supported device from any node of the network, without needing any type of configuration.

Answer (score 0):

As twopoint718 says, the "style" of Plan9 services is to provide a file-like interface.

It is impossible to list "everything" since anybody can write yet another service and expose it through a synthetic file interface.

I like to think of the Plan9 style as a big-chunk object based, or as Alan Kay says: "messaging based", system.  You build systems by implementing these servers (microservices in the current paradigm), define their interfaces and then integrate ever more comprehensive systems by "plumbing" the constituent services.